# Runtime Error in python: "Maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, recursion

I have a program that searches through a 2D list that represents a maze like so:

```
####################################
#S#  ##  ######## # #      #     # #
# #   #             # #        #   #
#   # ##### ## ###### # #######  # #
### # ##    ##      # # #     #### #
#   #    #  #######   #   ###    #E#
####################################
```

I understand what a recursion error is but I don't know why this code causes it as it should simply lead to finding the "E". Does anyone know how this possibly generates the error?

```
def solve(x,y):
    mazeList = loadMaze("sample.maze")    

    if mazeList[y][x] == "E":
        return "YOU'VE SOLVED THE MAZE!"
    elif mazeList[y][x+1] == " ":  #right
        mazeList[y][x+1] = ">"
        solve(x+1,y)
    elif mazeList[y+1][x] == " ":  #down
        mazeList[y+1][x] = "v"
        solve(x,y+1)    
    elif mazeList[y][x-1] == " ":  #left
        mazeList[y][x-1] = "<"
        solve(x-1,y)    
    elif mazeList[y-1][x] == " ":  #up
        mazeList[y-1][x] = "^"
        solve(x,y-1)
```

Comment: You realize that maze of the following type gives you an infinite loop right:
#######
#     #
#S    #
  # # #
  #   #
  #####
     E#  
#######

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You re-load `mazeList` *each time you call the function*.

So at the start of `solve()` you are right back at the starting conditions, and you end up running in circles.

Use a keyword argument to pass `mazeList` on to recursive calls, default it to `None` and only load the maze when it is still `None`:

```
def solve(x, y, mazeList=None):
    if mazeList is None:
        mazeList = loadMaze("sample.maze")
```

and pass `mazeList` to recursive calls.

Next problem is that you never return recursive calls; when you call `solve()` from within `solve()` you still need to return its result:

```
def solve(x, y, mazeList=None):
    if mazeList is None:
        mazeList = loadMaze("sample.maze")

    if mazeList[y][x] == "E":
        return "YOU'VE SOLVED THE MAZE!"
    elif mazeList[y][x+1] == " ":  #right
        mazeList[y][x+1] = ">"
        return solve(x+1,y,mazeList)
    elif mazeList[y+1][x] == " ":  #down
        mazeList[y+1][x] = "v"
        return solve(x,y+1,mazeList)    
    elif mazeList[y][x-1] == " ":  #left
        mazeList[y][x-1] = "<"
        return solve(x-1,y,mazeList)    
    elif mazeList[y-1][x] == " ":  #up
        mazeList[y-1][x] = "^"
        return solve(x,y-1,mazeList)
```

You'd still paint yourself in a corner with this technique; to recursively solve a maze, you need to try all paths, not just one, and give each recursive call a *copy* of the maze with the one chosen path marked out only.

You also always test for the *next* cell, but never take into account that that next cell could be the goal; you never move *onto* `E` because that cell is not equal to `' '`, so it's not a move candidate.

The following version *can* solve your maze:

```
directions = (
    (1, 0, '>'),
    (0, 1, 'v'),
    (-1, 0, '<'),
    (0, -1, '^'),
)

def solve(x, y, mazeList=None):
    if mazeList is None:
        mazeList = loadMaze("sample.maze")

    for dx, dy, char in directions:
        nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy

        if mazeList[ny][nx] == "E":
            return "YOU'VE SOLVED THE MAZE!"

        if mazeList[ny][nx] == " ":
            new_maze = [m[:] for m in mazeList]
            new_maze[ny][nx] = char
            result = solve(nx, ny, new_maze)
            if result is not None:
                return result
```

Testing for each direction separately was getting tedious, so I replaced that with a loop over a sequence of directions instead; each tuple is a change in x, in y and the character to use when moving in that direction.

Demo, with printout of the solved maze:

```
>>> def loadMaze(ignored):
...     maze = '''\
... ####################################
... #S#  ##  ######## # #      #     # #
... # #   #             # #        #   #
... #   # ##### ## ###### # #######  # #
... ### # ##    ##      # # #     #### #
... #   #    #  #######   #   ###    #E#
... ####################################
... '''
...     return [list(m) for m in maze.splitlines()]
... 
>>> directions = (
...     (1, 0, '>'),
...     (0, 1, 'v'),
...     (-1, 0, '<'),
...     (0, -1, '^'),
... )
>>> 
>>> def solve(x, y, mazeList=None):
...     if mazeList is None:
...         mazeList = loadMaze("sample.maze")   
...     for dx, dy, char in directions:
...         nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
...         if mazeList[ny][nx] == "E":
...             print '\n'.join([''.join(m) for m in mazeList])
...             return "YOU'VE SOLVED THE MAZE!"
...         if mazeList[ny][nx] == " ":
...             new_maze = [m[:] for m in mazeList]
...             new_maze[ny][nx] = char
...             result = solve(nx, ny, new_maze)
...             if result is not None:
...                 return result
... 
>>> solve(1, 1)
####################################
#S#  ##  ######## # #^>>>>>#  ^>># #
#v#^>>#    ^>>>     #^#   v>>>>#v>>#
#v>>#v#####^##v######^# #######  #v#
### #v##^>>>##v>>>>>#^# #     ####v#
#   #v>>>#  #######v>>#   ###    #E#
####################################
"YOU'VE SOLVED THE MAZE!"
```